# Error with watir trying to match copyright statement

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

Hi I'm using watir with rspec and am running into problems with the following chunk of code:

I cant understand what Im doing wrong. The exact error I get is "syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
      @b.text.include? "Ark © 1"

```
describe "Copyright statement" do 
   it "should exist" do 
    @b.text.include? "Ark © 1"
   end
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on the web while searching for the error **"invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)"**

Adding this line to the top helps with the copyright statement!

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Its just a simple comment at the top of the file, but it solves the problem with the copyright character and Rspec/Ruby 1.9.

Thank you everyone for all your help and support. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think your indentation is off the first end needs another space to line up.

```
describe "Copyright statement" do 
   it "should exist" do 
    @b.text.include? "Ark © 1"
   end 
end
```

Once you correct this you should be able to see what @ChuckvanderLinden and I think is the real problem - that you are missing and end, but without seeing the rest of the file we can't be sure.

I did come across this tip from Dave Thomas,

http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/12/ruby-19-can-check-your-indentation.html

if you run the file with the -w flag it will give you a much better idea of the problem and where exactly it is in your code.

```
ruby -w samplefile.rb
```

this will give you output similar to the following:

```
t.rb:5: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'if' at 3
t.rb:9: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 2
t.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Making it much easier to locate your error,

Comment: true, but this is Ruby, not Python so I doubt that is the cause of his problem

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden either that or he is missing and end http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/12/ruby-19-can-check-your-indentation.html

Comment: I agree, but I don't see one missing in the code he gave us.  without seeing more of that file its confusing to me why he might be getting that error.

Comment: Now THAT little trick (from the link you gave in your comment above) is worth the price of admission. I'd suggest amending your answer to include directions for how to use that -w switch (after neatening up his indentation)

Comment: Thanks for this tip by PragDave! Very Helpful in the future!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@SteveRobillard has addressed the missing end error message in his reply, but you have another big problem with how you are trying to use rspec there.  The problem is that you are not really doing anything with the results of the .include? method since there is no .should there.  Your code is executing the method, but just effectively tossing the 'true' or 'false' that is returned into the bit-bucket. That test will never fail because you are missing any kind of validation.   I think that line needs to be closer to

```
describe "Copyright statement" do 
   it "should exist" do 
     @b.text.should include "Ark © 1"
   end 
end
```

Correcting that probably will not fix your missing end issue, but without something like that, your 'tests' are not actually testing anything.

Also if it was me, I'd not only want to see that the copyright was somewhere in the html, but in a specific place such as the footer, which is typically inside some kind of container such as a div.  If that div had an id of 'footer' then that part of the code would be like this

```
it "should be found within the footer" do
  @browser.div(:id => 'footer').text.should include 'copyright © Yoyodyne 1984'
end
```

A good way to see rspec used with Watir is to look at the rspec files for watir itself, for example the spec for a div element and all the tests for what it should do is at https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/div_spec.rb

Comment: your answer is why I love SO people like you that go above and beyond to help others - Thanks

Comment: Hello @SteveRobillard and Chuck.. Your answers are very insightful. Especially Chuck's.. I basically started with plain Watir and was manually counting the errors and successes. I then moved to Rspec and am obviously not doing things the Rspec way. I also think I figured out the error. It has nothing to do with the indentation of the "end".. I got this error message last... "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/Users/buzz/Desktop/For Ark/Watir Tests/ark-home.rb:69: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
      @b.text.include? "Ark © #{Ark::YEAR}"

Comment: I think its an issue with the {copyright} character and Rspec... Don't know how it can be resolved though. I am also using code that evaluates to True or False in my Rspec tests :: eg:                              describe "Ark Search for People image" do 
    it "should exist" do 
      @b.image(:src => "http://ark.com/img/search_for_people.png").exists?
    end
  end

Comment: The problem with code that evaluates to true or false is that unless something is acting on that information, then it has no effect on the test.  You need to use a method that evaluates the result and reports the test as passing or failing.  this is 'assert' in many unit test frameworks.  In the case of BDD it is the use of the .should method (because it creates a more readable test)

Comment: Thanks so much @chuck. I rewrote all my tests using .should and now it plays nice with rspec!